# Сногосшибательно или сногсшибательно?

Tags: словообразование

В недавней статье* о современном состоянии нашего языка среди прочего другого уважаемый автор утверждает, что в слове «сногосшибательно» **самочинно повсеместно изымается** (не пишется и не произносится) соединительная гласная.

Автор говорит об этом факте, как о случае вандализма — «вопреки элементарному правилу о необходимости наличия буквы О в сложных словах (*умопомрачительно*, *малозначительно*, *зубодробительно*)».

Искал в НК: подтверждения существования этого слова там нет. А встречалось ли оно вам? Прав ли автор статьи вообще?

http://ruskline.ru/news_rl/2018/12/03/o_rusonenavistnichestve_i_absurde_v_russkom_yazyke/

Comment: _shampar: Искал в НК: подтверждения существования этого слова там нет. А встречалось ли оно вам?_ === См. https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&nfpr=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVoIHSmfjfAhUAAhAIHU95DGsQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1267&bih=601

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел и удивлён. Примеров достаточно, чтобы сказать — их у нас есть.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***сногсшибательный.***

Способ образования **без соединительной гласной (сращение + суффиксация).**

**Сращение** ― соединение двух или более слов исходного словосочетания без изменения их морфемного состава и при сохранении "живой синтаксической связи".

**Розенталь:**

http://www.rosental-book.ru/

§ 42. Сложные слова без соединительной гласной

5. С падежным окончанием в первой части образованы возникшие из словосочетаний слова ***сумасшедший, умалишённый*** и т. п.

**Комментарий**

Мне кажется, что автор из тех людей, которые сначала придумывают идею, а потом подбирают подходящие под нее факты. При этом они рассчитывают на читателя не слишком осведомленного, как, например, в данном случае.

Автор как раз сам допускает **элементарное незнание способов образования слов в русском языке.**

После  этого какое может быть доверие к статье!

Comment: Однако, допускающих «элементарное незнание» так много, что не счесть: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&newwindow=1&ei=_GFDXMyUFIWLmgWIpYSgCQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjMgpLvsvrfAhWFhaYKHYgSAZQ4ChDy0wMIVA&biw=1530&bih=726

Comment: Очень многим форма "сногосшибательно" ближе и понятнее, так как соединительная гласная препятствует стечению согласных. Но как образовать такое слово на основе сочетания "сшибать с ног"? Нужно предлог превратить в приставку и добавить соединительную гласную? Вероятно, это будет прецедентом в русской грамматике и новым способом образования сложных слов. А вот автор статьи утверждает, что будто бы все сложные слова должны иметь соединительную гласную, а это далеко не так.

Comment: Не то, чтобы «понятнее». Пробовал понять разницу в значении, так она ускользает, не формулируется. Но у «сногосшибательно» определённо есть шарм.

Answer (score 2):

Автор сам привёл слово "малозначительно", где буква "о" - не *соединительная гласная*, как он предполагает. К "**сногсшибательно**" же по способу словообразования (в слове, не являющемся техническим термином или числительным, стыкуются согласные) ближе слово "*испоко**нв**ечно(-ый, -ен)*", встречающееся в книгах. К таким словам можно отнести и его авторское сложное слово "какбыкер" (от "как бы") из той же статьи. Здесь тоже составляющие исходного сочетания остаются грамматически взаимосвязанными (как в "*с-ног-сшибать*"), в то время как соединительная гласная разрушила бы такую связь.

Comment: В слове "малозначительно"соединительная гласная - о.